# Как вводить массив строк string без заданного размера, чтобы при нажатии enter ввод останавливался?

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Например, у меня есть массив строк `string str[256]` и я через `getline (cin, str[i], ' ')` в цикле `for` записываю слова. Но ввод не остановится, если не задать размер поменьше. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии enter ввод останавливался? Это должен быть именно `string` массив.

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Приведите свой код ввода, что хотите получить, а что получается.

Comment: Не сделаете  так. Вы читаете символ перевода строки и выбрасываете при вводе std::string, потому что '\n' тоже разделитель. getline тут вообще не нужен, просто читайте  в объекты string

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что при вводе std::string из потока, читаются символы_разделители и выбрасываются. Поэтому вы таким образом не сможете знать был ли достигнут терминатор. Хоть это не важно, но тут `getline`  вовсе не нужна_ вы и так прочтете строку до пробела.

Для решения вопроса с вашим подходом(читать строки до символа терминатора, придется считывать из буфера символ и проверить:

- если считанный символ является терминатором(в данном случаи `'\n'`),
  то выйти из цикла;
- если считанный символ не ваш разделитель(в данном случаи пробел), то
  положить обратно в буфер и читать строку.

Код может быть таким:

```
const char term = '\n';
for (int i = 0;  i < 255;  ++i)
{    
    char c = cin.get();
    if (c == term)
        break;
    else if (c != ' ') {
        cin.unget();
        cin >> str[i];
        //использование можно добавить
        cout << str[i] << ' ';
    }
    //...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Сперва прочитайте строку целиком, в уже потом, разбирайте ее на отдельные слова.

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line); // читаем строку целиком
std::istringstream line_stream(line); // делаем из этой строки отдельный поток ввода
for( std::string word; line_stream>>word ; )
    words.push_back(word);
```